# Using cutadapt adapter file inputs in Snakemake

Tags: python, bash, shell, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am new to Snakemake, trying to port my BASH code to work with Snakemake rules. Disclaimer out of the way, I am attempting to demultiplex a fastq file with cutadapt in a shell block, using a fasta file with headers and adapter sequences. Samplenames matching the fasta headers are loaded in and specified as a wild card in rule all:

```
rule all:
input:
    expand([os.path.join(outDir, "reads_trim.fq"),
            os.path.join(outDir, "{name}.tmp")], name=samples_list)
```

The reads_trim file is a standard, concatenated fastq file (from Nanopore sequencing). My problem is that this rule is run 12 times, since I have 12 samples in my "samples_list". I then get 12 output files, as I should, with correct naming, but they all contain the exact same. I wonder if output would be correct if it would run just once instead, but haven't found a way to force that behaviour.

```
rule demultiplex:
""" Demultiplex Nextera-styled barcodes using the compiled barcode fasta file """
input:
    barcodeFile=os.path.join(outDir, "barcodes_used.fasta"),
    fastqFile=os.path.join(outDir, "reads_trim.fq")
output: os.path.join(outDir, "{name}.tmp")
message: "Demultiplexing trimmed reads"
log: "logs/cutadapt/demultiplexing_{name}.log"
shell:
    """
    cutadapt -e 0.20 -O 10 -m 15 -M 15 -g file:{input.barcodeFile} -o {output} {input.fastqFile}
    """
```

Any idea how to get the standard behaviour where one file goes in, x files come out with different output (where the adapter was found)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with cutadapt for demultiplexing but from a quick look at the
[docs](https://cutadapt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide.html#demultiplexing), I
think you want something along these lines (I simplified your original code):

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{name}.tmp", name= samples_list),

rule demultiplex:
    input:
        barcodeFile= "barcodes_used.fasta",
        fastqFile= "reads_trim.fq"
    output: 
        expand("{name}.tmp", name=samples_list),
    shell:
        r"""
        cutadapt ... -g file:{input.barcodeFile} -o {{name}}.tmp {input.fastqFile}
        """
```

If the input `reads_trim.fq` produces all the 12 output files in one shot, then
you need to list all the 12 outputs in the `output` directive. I used the
`expand()` function for that. Note that `{{name}}.tmp` has double curly braces
to tell snakemake that it's not a wildcard but it's to be read exactly as
`{name}` (as per cutadapt docs if I read them right).

By the way, are you sure that cutadapt can demultiplex Nanopore?

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you! I was of the (wrong) impression that expanding the output was not necessary since I had it in the rule all. This did the trick. Regarding cutadapt and Nanopore, we have found that it works fine if you use Illumina's Nextera adapters (specifically the UDP ones), as they differ enough to be used with Nanopore